# Numerically integrating solution obtained from NDSolve method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

In the following example, $u(x)$ is found numerically using NDSolve method.

```
 F = 1/1000
    h = 12000/1000
    d = 10/10
    L = 1000
    W = 3
    phi[x_] := 
     Piecewise[{{(1/2)*(1 - Tanh[((L*x)/(d))]), 
        x <= 1/2}, {(1/2)*(1 + Tanh[((L*(x - L/L))/(d))]), x > 1/2}}]
    vE[x_] := x*(1 - x)*4
    s = NDSolve[{u''[x] == (h*L*L/(d*d))*phi[x]*phi[x]*u[x] - 
         F*L*L*(1 - phi[x]), u[-W*d/L] == 0, u[1 + W*d/L] == 0}, 
      u, {x, -W*d/L, 1 + W*d/L}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
      WorkingPrecision -> 40, InterpolationOrder -> All]
    diff[x_] := (u[x] - vE[x])*(u[x] - vE[x])
    Plot[Evaluate[{diff[x]} /. s], {x, W*d/L, 1 - W*d/L}, 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

Which works perfectly.  I need to see what is mean square error between obtained solution and another function $vE(x)$.

```
sum = 0;
Do[
 first = W*d/L;
 second = 1 - W*d/L;
 {sum = sum + diff[first + (i/100)*(second - first)]},
 {i, 0, 100, 1}]
Evaluate[sum]
```

but this gives only expression but not value. I think this is because $u(x)$ 
is obtained at discrete points only and is not defined on the points on which I have calculated error. I also tried using integration,

```
intVal = NIntegrate[({u[x]} /. s - vE[x])*({u[x]} /. s - vE[x]), {x, 
   W*d/L, 1 - W*d/L}]
```

but this gives long error message ending with,

```
 "...is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"
```

How can I evaluate this integral?

Comment: `Evaluate[sum]` gives number if you use `diff[x_] := (u[x] - vE[x])*(u[x] - vE[x])/.s`.
Then `NIntegrate[diff[x], {x, W*d/L, 1 - W*d/L}]` works too. The current problem for your `NIntegrate` is that `-` has lower precedence than `/.`, which you can easily check out by selecting the code click by click

Comment: on thing to note `NDSolve` returns a list of solutions, even though in this case there is only one solution, so you should be doing `/. s[[1]]`. (as is you get a bunch of superfluous `{}` in the results )

Comment: @Coolwater, it worked with your suggestion, thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate the mean square error `mse` at the same time as computing `u[x]`.

```
s = NDSolve[{
    u''[x] == (h*L*L/(d*d))*phi[x]*phi[x]*u[x] - F*L*L*(1 - phi[x]),
    u[-W*d/L] == 0, u[1 + W*d/L] == 0,
    mse'[x] == (u[x] - vE[x])^2, mse[-W*d/L] == 0},
   {u, mse}, {x, -W*d/L, 1 + W*d/L}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
   WorkingPrecision -> 40, InterpolationOrder -> All];

 Plot[Evaluate[mse[x] /. s], {x, W*d/L, 1 - W*d/L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You seem to be interested in this change:

```
mse[1 - W*d/L] - mse[W*d/L] /. First@s

(* 8198.070964448656291179158359833465311096 *)
```

---

The problem with the code

```
 intVal = NIntegrate[({u[x]} /. s - vE[x])*({u[x]} /. s - vE[x]), {x, W*d/L, 1 - W*d/L}]
```

is a syntax issue.  The expression that `/.` tries to apply is `s - vE[x]`.  This can be seen from the [`TreeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TreeForm.html) of the expression:

```
Hold[({u[x]} /. s - vE[x])] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In other words, `ReplaceAll` has lower precedence than `Plus` (represented by the minus sign).  The proper code is

```
intVal = NIntegrate[((u[x] /. First@s) - vE[x])^2, {x, W*d/L, 1 - W*d/L},
  WorkingPrecision -> 40]

(* 8198.070964448656291179224357022321689725 *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael for the complete explanation..!!

Comment: @alekhine You're welcome. :)