# Implicitly inverting a function from numerical solution

Tags: functions, piecewise, inverse, implicit

I have the following piecewise continuous function:

```
myfun[a_, l1_, l2_] = 
 Piecewise[{{a^2, a < l1}, 
            {a - l1 + l1^2, a >= l1 && a < l2}, 
            {l2 - l1 + l1^2 + Log[a - l2 + 1], a >= l2}}]
```

The function is defined by a value $a$ and two parameters $l_1$ and $l_2$ and if I plot it, appears as:

```
Plot[Evaluate[myfun[a, l1, l2] /. {l1 -> 1.5, l2 -> 3.2}], {a, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, I would like to invert the numerical solution given by $myfun==2.0$ with respect to a, which is a function depending on $l_1$ and $l_2$. I tried to do it "in a delayed way" with

```
myInvFun[l1_, l2_] := x /. FindRoot[myfun[x, l1, l2] == 2.0, {l, 0}]
```

But this does not help me, since if I try to plot the following

```
Plot[Evaluate[myInvFun[l1, l2] /. {l2 -> 3.5}], {l1, 0, 3.5}]
```

errors appear:

[image]

How can I make the inverse function usable as an explicit function even if I use only a definition from numerical solution?

P.S. I had a look to answers like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/solve-trigonometric-equation/27984#27984) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58807/numerically-integrating-solution-obtained-from-ndsolve-method) but either way I could not find a way to solve my problem

Answer (score 5):

This is simple enough to do analytically.. assuming `l2>l1` you can readily find the transition points and invert each piece of the `Piecewise` expression:

```
myfuninv[x_, l1_, l2_ /; l2 > l1] = Piecewise[{
   {Sqrt[x], x <= l1^2},
   {x + l1 - l1^2, l1^2 < x <= l2 + l1^2 - l1},
   {Exp[x + l1 - l2 - l1^2] - 1 + l2,  l2 + l1^2 - l1 < x}}]
Plot[ myfuninv[2, l1, 3.5] , {l1, 0, 3.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: ...in the words of Field Marshal the Viscount Sir William Slim: “Thinking is the cheapest and one of the most effective long-range weapons.” (+1)

Answer (score 4):

You can see what you get with the body of your function `myInvFun` over parameter instances:

```
In[215]:= FindRoot[myfun[x, 2, 5] == 2.0, {x, 0}]

Out[215]= {x -> 0.}

FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x} = {0.}. 
Try perturbing the initial point(s). >>
```

So, if you change your definition as advised by the message you'll get results you might expect:

```
myInvFun[l1_, l2_] := x /. FindRoot[myfun[x, l1, l2] == 2.0, {x, 0.1}]

Plot[Evaluate[myInvFun[l1, 3.5]], {l1, 0, 3.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### General Inversion

You can use `FindRoot` to do a general inversion of a `Piecewise` function.

The strategy will be to extract the smooth continuous function from the piecewise function and use that as input to `FindRoot`.

Below is a copy of your function:

```
myfun[a_, l1_, l2_] = Piecewise[{
   {a^2, a < l1},
   {a - l1 + l1^2, 
    a >= l1 && a < l2}, {l2 - l1 + l1^2 + Log[a - l2 + 1], a >= l2}
   }]
```

which has three regions that contain three different functions.

`Part` can be used to access the function that is valid in each region

```
myfun[a, l1, l2][[1, 1, 1]]
(* a^2 *)

myfun[a, l1, l2][[1, 2, 1]]
(* a - l1 + l1^2 *)

myfun[a, l1, l2][[1, 3, 1]]
(* -l1 + l1^2 + l2 + Log[1 + a - l2] *)
```

Now we will define the inverse function which takes the limits as well as `myfun` as input arguments. `myfun` will be used to set the limits of the inverse `Piecewise` function as well as being an input to `FindRoot`.

```
myInvFun[y_, l1_, l2_, myfun_] := Piecewise[{
   {
    Module[{a, fun},
     fun[a_] = myfun[a, l1, l2][[1, 1, 1]];
     FindRoot[fun[a] == y, {a, l1/2}][[1, 2]]
     ],
    y < myfun[l1, l1, l2]
    },
   {
    Module[{a, fun},
     fun[a_] = myfun[a, l1, l2][[1, 2, 1]];
     FindRoot[fun[a] == y, {a, (l1 + l2)/2}][[1, 2]]
     ],
    y >= myfun[l1, l1, l2] && y < myfun[l2, l1, l2]
    },
   {
    Module[{a, fun},
     fun[a_] = myfun[a, l1, l2][[1, 3, 1]];
     FindRoot[
       l2 - l1 + l1^2 + Log[a - l2 + 1] == y, {a, l2 + 0.5}][[1, 2]]
     ],
    y >= myfun[l2, l1, l2]
    }
   }]
```

Now `myInvFun` can be treated like any ordinary function. For example:

```
myInvFun[2, 1.5, 3.2, myfun]
(* 1.41421 *)
```

We can validate that the inverse matches `myfun` by plotting `myfun` and using `ParametricPlot` for `myInvFun`.

```
Show[
 Plot[myfun[a, 1.5, 3.2], {a, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Black],
 ParametricPlot[{myInvFun[y, 1.5, 3.2, myfun], y}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

They do indeed match.

### Specific Inversion

Clearly you can simply replace the argument `a` in `myFunInv` with 2 if you want to plot the inverse as function of `l1`.

```
Plot[myInvFun[2, l1, 3.5, myfun], {l1, 0, 3.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

The following uses `NDSolve` to construct interpolations along lines in the domain.  We then construct an interpolation between the solutions to `NDSolve`, which represents `a` as a function of `l1` and `l2`.

```
{dadl1, dadl2} = 
  grad = PiecewiseExpand /@ (-D[myfun[a, l1, l2], {{l1, l2}}]/
        D[myfun[a, l1, l2], a]) /. ComplexInfinity -> 0 // Quiet;

sols = Table[
   Block[{l1a = 0, l1b = 3.5, l2},
    Module[{flag = True, res, dl = 0, n = 0},
     While[flag,
      Check[
       l2 = l2b + (-1)^n dl;
       res = 
        NDSolveValue[{a'[l1] == (dadl1 /. a -> a[l1]), a[0] == 2}, 
         a, {l1, l1a, l1b}, PrecisionGoal -> 10]; flag = False,
       flag = True;
       n += 1;
       dl += 0.001]
      ];
     {l2, res}]
    ],
   {l2b, 0., 3.5, 0.1}];

ClearAll[if];
if[sols : {{_?NumericQ, _InterpolatingFunction} ..}] := 
  if[sols[[All, 1]], sols[[All, 2]], 
   Nearest[sols[[All, 1]] -> Automatic]];
if[l2data_, ifns : {__InterpolatingFunction}, nf_NearestFunction][
  l1in_?NumericQ, l2in_?NumericQ] := Module[{i2, $l2, $a},
  {i2[1], i2[2]} = nf[l2in] /. {{1} -> {1, 2},
      {Length@l2data} -> {Length@l2data - 1, Length@l2data},
      {n_ /; l2in <= l2data[[n]]} :> {n - 1, n}, {n_} :> {n, n + 1}};
  {$l2[1], $l2[2]} = l2data[[{i2[1], i2[2]}]];
  $a[1] = ifns[[i2[1]]][l1in];
  $a[2] = ifns[[i2[2]]][l1in];
  InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{$l2[1]}, $a[1]}, {{$l2[2]}, $a[2]}}, l2in]
  ]

afn = if[sols];

Plot3D[afn[l1, l2], {l1, 0, 3.5}, {l2, 0, 3.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]